# How can I get username in template with below condition please tell me?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-template-filters

**I want to know i AM not found mistake in below code if else in e.html Can anyone tell me how to get the username of a user in the below code. My condition seems not to be working
/.......................................................................................................**

```
e.html
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            {% if request.user  %}
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Welcome{{request.user}}</a>
{% else %}
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="">no</a>
{% endif %}

        </a>

views.py
def registration_view(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    template = 'home/login.html'

    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("post")
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            print("okk valid")
            if User.objects.filter(username=form.cleaned_data['username']).exists():
                messages.error(request,'Username already exists')
                return render(request, template, {
                    'form': form,
                    'error_message': 'Username already exists.'
                })
            elif User.objects.filter(email=form.cleaned_data['email']).exists():
                messages.error(request,'Email already exists')
                return render(request, template, {
                    'form': form,
                    'error_message': 'Email already exists.'
                })
            elif form.cleaned_data['password'] != form.cleaned_data['password_repeat']:
                messages.error(request,'Password do not match ')
                return render(request, template, {
                    'form': form,
                    'error_message': 'Passwords do not match.'
                })
            else:
                # Create the user:
                user = User.objects.create_user(
                    form.cleaned_data['username'],
                    form.cleaned_data['email'],
                    form.cleaned_data['password']
                )
                user.first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
                user.last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
                # user.date = form.cleaned_data['date']
                print("save reached")
                user.save()
                # Login the user
                login(request, user)
                messages.success(request,"Created your account succcessfully in thumbsapp ")
                return redirect('home')
```

Handle login function

def handlelogin(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

```
    loginusername = request.POST.get('username','')
    loginpassword = request.POST.get('password','')
    userr = authenticate(username=loginusername, password=loginpassword)
    # post = User.objects.filter(username=loginusername,password=loginpassword)
    if userr is not None:
        login(request,userr)       
        return redirect('post')
        return render(request,'user_homeview')
        return HttpResponse('logged in')

    else:
        messages.error(request, "Invalid credintials your Username or Password incorrect! ")
        return render(request, 'home/login.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use modelforms. And you don't need to check if the username or email exist, just add to your model:

```
     unique=True.
```

To add new user with modelform :

```
   form.save()
```

Comment: I am not using models for creating account

Answer (score 0):

```
e.html
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Welcome  {{request.user.username}}

        </a>
```

`{{request.user}}` returns the user object, you can access all the user parameters using `{{request.user.username}}` `{{request.user.email}}` `{{request.user.first_name}}` and so on

Comment: I have also tried but didn't get User object can you tell me why i am not get username by request.user and thankyou

Comment: {% if request.user  %}
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Welcome{{user.username}}</a>
    {% else %}
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="">no</a>
    {% endif %}